# A question on HCF and Equations. The question is given in the picture below.

Tags: polynomials, factoring, systems-of-equations

[image: HCF]

Please also mention how you arrived at the answer.

Comment: I STILL DIDNT GET THIS ONE....OTHER ANSWERS ARE WELCOME...

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

As $(x-4,x-5)=1$

$x-4$ must divide $x^2-x-a$

Now use [Factor theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem)

Comment: But How I didnt Understand.....

Comment: @Sudhanshu, what is your confusion?

Comment: How  (x−4,x−5)=1

Comment: @Sudhanshu, Let integer $d$ divides both of them. Then $d$ will divide $(x-4)-(x-5)=1$

Comment: I'm just confused...I'm not getting this one.?  Firstly what is the use of doing this : (x−4)−(x−5)=1  ais this some theorem I dont know....??  Because the product of (x-4) and (x-5) is the LCM... And how will I arrive at the answer.?? Is there some formula linking HCF and the two polynomials given...??  @lab bhattacharjee

Comment: @Sudhanshu, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Procedure